# How to make a computed relationship dependent upon all records of a different Model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say I have a `Car` and a `User` `DS.Model`s, and would like to present the user on their profile page a list of cars that they might like to drive, so in the `user` template I have set the `contentBinding` of a simple `Bootstrap.Forms.Select` to `suggestedCars`.

And in the user.coffee class file (as this is business logic):

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
     ...
  suggestedCars: (-> App.Car.all().filter(-> true)).property('UNKNOWN')
```

And for the life of me I can't figure out what to put in UNKNOWN to have it work how it would be supposed to. I need to find out the key path for binding to all cars. All sensible attempts from pouring through the Ember sources have left me with no recourse. Setting UNKNOWN to just fullName allows me, by changing the user's name on the profile, to see that the filter code does work as expected, as soon as the name is changed the select is populated with all the cars.

As an interesting side note, removing even this trivial filter from the system must change something with the timing of the loading so that the select is populated just from all() and an empty property, but of course that does not change when the Cars are changed.

Obviously I would like to do something a bit more complex than 'true' as a filter (and I'm not really dealing with Cars either), but I have reduced the problem down to the basics to find what the problem is, and it seems to be this accursed key path, or perhaps my naive approach.

Thanks so very much for your time, attention and assistance.

Comment: can you provide a jsbin showing more of what your setup looks like?

Comment: Sounds to me like something to be done in the `UserController`? Have the `suggestedCars` as a computed property watching `content.username` (if `User` is the `content/model` of the `UserController`). So everytime `content.username` changes, `suggestedCars` will change and return whatever you want (.all() or .filter())... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@colymba has basically answered the question in the comments. Even if it is business logic, this kind of computed property may be best suited in a controller. Ember's MVC and frontend MVC's in general, is different in this regard, to the server-side.

You need something like this,

```
App.CarsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['users'],
  usersBinding: 'controllers.users',

  suggestedCars: function() {
    // return something based on both users and cars
  }.property('users.@each', 'model.@each')
});
```

Comment: I see, so you're saying that I would create a subordinate UserCarsController that would check what the current user is from the UserController, and use that current user to perform the filtration as a computed property of the models of both controllers? That sounds reasonable.